# Java: Get List<> Items from one class into JComboBox of another class

Tags: java, swing, list, jcombobox

Here's the thing:

I created a 'cocktailbar' software, and I have the following classes:

- Cocktail,
- CocktailBar,
- CreateNewCPanel,
- HelloPanel,
- SearchCPanel,
- ShowAllCPanel,
- CocktailMixerGUI,
- Ingredients.

Now: When adding a new `Cocktail` in the `CreateNewCPanel`, I add the cocktail to a List in the `CocktailBar` class.

```
Box buttonBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
JButton speicherButton = new JButton("Speichern");
speicherButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        neuerC.setCName(cName.getText());
        neuerC.fuegeZubereitungHinzu(zubereitungTextArea.getText());
        CocktailBar.addCocktail(neuerC);
```

Now I need to see all created cocktails in a 'dropdown' menu in the `ShowAllCPanel`. I've got the following:

```
//Adding the DropDown Menu, first a Box, then a ComboBox inside.
Box cDropDownBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
cDropDownBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

JComboBox cChoose = new JComboBox();
groesseEinsetzen(cChoose, 500, 20);

cChoose.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.LEFT);
cDropDownBox.add(cChoose);
```

But now I am wondering how do I get my List from the `CocktailBar` class into the `ShowAllCPanel`?

edit: forgot to mention: i have a getter in the CocktailBar class, and i already tried:

```
        cChoose.addItem(CocktailBar.getCocktails());
```

within the comboBox in the ShowAllCPanel, but it doesnt show up anything in the dropdown.

thanks to @Do Re, i inserted this:

```
 //Adding the DropDown Menu, first a Box, then a ComboBox inside.
    Box cDropDownBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    cDropDownBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

    JComboBox cChoose = new JComboBox();

    if (CocktailBar.getCocktails() != null){

        for (Cocktail c : CocktailBar.getCocktails())
            cChoose.addItem(c);
    }
```

but still - when running, the dropdown list stays empty.

Comment: have your tried createing a `getter`for the list?

Comment: yeah, i forgot to mention that... i tried:

        cChoose.addItem(CocktailBar.getCocktails());

but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: what does `getCocktails()` return? What was the error?

Comment: public static List<Cocktail> getCocktails(){
  return cocktails;
 }

no errors, just nothing in the combobox to see

Comment: see my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, you created a getter for the cocktails.

Try something like this

```
for (Coctail c : CocktailBar.getCocktails())
    cChoose.addItem(c);
```

This iterates over the list of cocktails and adds each item seperately rather than adding a list of Cocktails at once.

**Edit**

try

```
 cDropDownBox.revalidate();
 cDropDownBox.repaint();
```

or

```
cChoose.revalidate();
cChoose.repaint();
```

Comment: where should i put it? i tried it just before the dropdownbox is added to the label, with no effect